# configuring how to run my robot framework test on gitlab-ci

Tags: python-3.x, continuous-integration, robotframework, gitlab-ci

Im trying the new feature gitlab-ci. And configuring the gitlab-ci.yml file for my flask app which is app.py and a tester robot framework which is test.robot

i'm new to this and tried some sources but it all wont work for me.

here is my .gitlab-ci.yml file:

```
image: python:3.6-stretch

stages:
  - robot_test
  - deploy

before_script:
    - pip install -r requirements.txt

test:
  stage: robot_test
  script:
    - python -m robotframework discover tests
```

It should run the test in my test.robot

Answer (score 0):

The [stages](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#stages) are used to define stages that can be used by jobs and is defined globally.

From the doc:

```
stages:
  - build
  - test
  - deploy
```

> - First, all jobs of `build` are executed in parallel.
> - If all jobs of `build` succeed, the `test` jobs are executed in parallel.
> - If all jobs of `test` succeed, the `deploy` jobs are executed in parallel.

In your case:

```
stages:
  - test
  - deploy
```

Within `test`, you would execute `robot_test`.